# Issue setting PHP cookie with included files

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following script which creates a cookie and updates a site counter in a database record if the user hasn't visited the website in a day, else, it will just display the current count of visits. Currently the cookie is displaying NULL every time I reload the index page and therefore the table keeps getting updated more than it should. How do I maintain the cookie value on the index page when this script is included?

```
if (empty($_COOKIE["visits"])) {
            // increment the counter in the database
            mysql_query("UPDATE visit_counter ".
                     " SET counter = counter + 1 ".
                     " WHERE id = 1");

            /* Query visit_counter table and assign counter
               value to the $visitors variable */
            $QueryResult = mysql_query("SELECT counter ".
                    " FROM visit_counter WHERE id = 1");

            // Place query results into an associative array if there are any
            if (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE) {
                $visitors = $row['counter'];
            } else {
                // else if this is the first visitor set variable to 1
                $visitors = 1; 
            }

            // Set cookie value
            setcookie("visits", $visitors, time()+(60*60*24));
        } else {
            $visitors = $_COOKIE["visits"];
        }
```

The cookie script is included in an index file, so the following would be the index file...

```
<?php include("Includes/cookie.php"); ?>
var_dump($_COOKIE["visits"]);        /* Always returns NULL on this page but
                                        returns the cookies real value if 
                                         run straight from cookie.php script */


    /* Some main page content goes here */


   /* The cookie value is echoed in the footer file that is included by
      creating a statement that says echo "total visitors: ".$visitors; */
   <?php include("Includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask that question yesterday?

Comment: @Sébastien He must have misread that quote "Smile it's another day".

Comment: Before you include the cookie.php, set `$visits=$_COOKIE['visits']`, than use it in other file.

Comment: @skobaljic thank you for the suggestion, but it still doesn't seem to be working, I just don't get what the issue is.

Comment: As Antonio said below, could be the problem with the cookie scope. Try to find out where the cookie is available. You can use some developer tools, or simply, while browsing, run this `document.cookie.split("visits=").pop().split(";").shift();` in browser inspector, or Firebug. Another possibility is: the server allows only HttpOnly cookies, which means: the cookie won't be set unless client sent HTTP request.

Comment: I ended up finding out that I needed to include the cookie before the HTML headers on the page, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on `set_cookie`
set it from:

```
<?php
// Set cookie value
setcookie("visits", $visitors, time()+(60*60*24));
?>
```

to

```
<?php
// Set cookie value
setcookie("visits", $visitors, time()+(60*60*24),'/'); // Define the cookie path to be used on this domain
?>
```

Good luck

Comment: I thought this parameter would work and had tried it but it still doesn't work, I'm stumped.